# Convert to markdown but how to set caret appropriate (in Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, text, markdown

I can not come up with a suitable solution...

```
<p class="session" contenteditable="true">
    Everything contained <b>**within**</b> this div is editable in browsers
    that support <code>`HTML5`</code>. Go on, give it a try: click it and
    start typing.
</p>
```

I want to add the appropriate HTML-tags while typing.

Of course it is no problem doing it by simple regex replacements. But I have problems setting the caret at the right place.

Say, in the example above, I want to emphasize the word "try". While typing the right `*` first and then the left star `*`, the text is converted to `<i>*try*</i>` but I want to preserve the position of the caret (set the the caret after the left `*`). And of cource vice versa, where the right `*` is set at last.

I find it more difficult to set the part `contained <b>**within**</b> this` say underlined. `_contained <b>**within**</b> this_` becomes `<u>_contained <b>**within**</b> this_</u>`. So we are not in the same node.

I can think of complicated solutions, but since I am no expert in these text conversions techniques (range, window selection etc.) I wonder if there is a well known pratice of doing it.

Comment: could you explain " While typing the right * first and then the left star *, the text is converted to <i>*try*</i> but I want to preserve the position of the caret (set the the caret after the left *). And of cource vice versa, where the right * is set at last"

Comment: There are two situations. The user types a `*` first, writes text `try` or set the cursor after the altesdy existing word `try`and types the last `*`.

OR the user could write the word `try` (or whatever), type the last `*` first and then moves in front of the word `try` and types the first `*`.

In case one, the cursor should be here `<i>*try*</i>|` in the second case, the cursor should be here `<i>*|try*</i>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbu8h0cp/)

I have tried to get the caret position as a first step and in the second step i have tried to put the caret back to the position .

```
$('.session').keyup(function(){
//alert("happening");
var sel = window.getSelection();
var offset=sel.anchorOffset;
// you can change the text in div by uncommeting the line below and replace your text  with mathcing regex .
//$('.session').text($('.session').text().replace('/(\*.\*)+/','<i>$1<i>'));
setCaret(offset);
$('.session')
});

function setCaret(offset) {

    var el = $('.session');
    //alert();
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();

    range.setStart(el[0].childNodes[0],offset);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    el.focus();
}
```

You need to figure out how to change the text in the div as per your needs. While replacing the text inside the div also maintain the formatting so that the solution works.